# REGEX: put all the words in a paragraph on a single line

Tags: notepad++, regex, sublime-text-3

**as seen below, each line in all the paraphrases is unfinished. The words at the beginning of each line in the paragraph are not a continuation of the previous line. I'm interested in connecting all the lines in the paraphrase without having any word breaks.**

```
When the water rises up to F, the piece at A will be visible; when it
reaches G, both A and B will be visible; and when it comes up to H,
all three pieces will be visible.


_Artificial Earthquake and Volcano._

Grind an equal quantity of fresh iron filings with pure sulphur, till
the whole be reduced to a fine powder. Be careful not to let any wet
come near it. Then bury about thirty pounds of it a foot deep in the
earth, and in about six or eight hours the ground will heave and
swell, and shortly after send forth smoke and flames like a burning
mountain. If the earth is raised in a conical shape, it will be no bad
miniature resemblance of one of the burning mountains.


_Artificial Illuminations._

A very pleasing exhibition may be made with very little trouble or
expense, in the following manner: Provide a box, which you fit up with
architectural designs cut out on pasteboard; prick small holes in
those parts of the building where you wish the illuminations to
appear, observing, that in proportion to the perspective, the holes
are to be made smaller; and on the near objects the holes are to be
made larger. Behind these designs thus perforated, you fix a lamp or
candle, but in such a manner that the reflection of the light shall
only shine through the holes; then placing a light of just sufficient
brilliance to show the design of the buildings before it, and making a
hole for the sight at the front end of the box, you will have a very
tolerable representation of illuminated buildings.
```

**THE OUTPUT**

```
When the water rises up to F, the piece at A will be visible; when it reaches G, both A and B will be visible; and when it comes up to H, all three pieces will be visible.


_Artificial Earthquake and Volcano._

Grind an equal quantity of fresh iron filings with pure sulphur, till the whole be reduced to a fine powder. Be careful not to let any wet come near it. Then bury about thirty pounds of it a foot deep in the earth, and in about six or eight hours the ground will heave and swell, and shortly after send forth smoke and flames like a burning mountain. If the earth is raised in a conical shape, it will be no bad miniature resemblance of one of the burning mountains.


_Artificial Illuminations._

A very pleasing exhibition may be made with very little trouble or expense, in the following manner: Provide a box, which you fit up with architectural designs cut out on pasteboard; prick small holes in those parts of the building where you wish the illuminations to appear, observing, that in proportion to the perspective, the holes are to be made smaller; and on the near objects the holes are to be made larger. Behind these designs thus perforated, you fix a lamp or candle, but in such a manner that the reflection of the light shall only shine through the holes; then placing a light of just sufficient brilliance to show the design of the buildings before it, and making a hole for the sight at the front end of the box, you will have a very tolerable representation of illuminated buildings.
```

**My regex doesn't work very good:**

FIND: `^(.*?)$(\K.*)\r`

REPLACE BY: `\2`

**OR (a better one)**

FIND: `^(.*?)$(\R)`

REPLACE BY: `\1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Notepad++, may be it works with SublimeText.

---

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\R+_.+_\R+(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\R`
- Replace with:    # A space
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\R+         # 1 or more any kind of linebreak
_.+_        # 1 or more any character surounded by underscores
\R+         # 1 or more any kind of linebreak
(*SKIP)     # skip this match
(*FAIL)     # and considere it failed
|           # OR
\R          # any kind of linebreak
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A very simple and useful regex formula:

**FIND:** `([^\r\n])\R([^\r\n])`

**REPLACE BY:** `\1 \2`

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\R(?=.)`
- Replace with: `(leave empty)`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

Comment: This removes lines above and under titles, i.e.: `_Artificial Illuminations._`

Comment: yes, I see now. It is not perfect my regex, but it can be a starting point.